# AngularJS: Can't resolve Error: [$parse:syntax]

Tags: angularjs

I'm brand new at AngularJS, watching a Lynda.com video series on it, "Up and Running with AngularJS
with Ray Villalobos." I can't get past this error notice. I'm using WAMP to display an external Ajax file data.json with an $http service.

I've looked up "[$parse:syntax]" on this site and none of the solutions seem to fit my case. I entered my json into jsonlint.com/ and it validates. (First time using json.)

The error points out an unexpected token (see message below), and I don't know what part of my code is causing it. Looking up "unexpected token" in Google hasn't helped.

**html:**

```
<div ng-controller = "MyController"> <!-- ties this template to MyController. (Case matters! myController doesn't work.) -->
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in cars track by &index"> <!-- Needed to add "track by &index" to remove "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]" notice-->
    <div class="section">
        <h2>{{item.model}}</h2>
        <!-- Needed to chg <img src to <img ng-src -->
        <img ng-src="images/{{item.shortname}}.jpg" width="200px" alt="Photo of {{item.model}}" title="Photo of {{item.model}}">
        <h3>{{item.description}}</h3>
        <p>{{item.edition + ', ' + item.bodytype}}</p>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**controllers.js:**

```
var myNameSpace = angular.module('myApp', []);

myNameSpace.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) { 
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.cars = data;
    });
});
```

**Error:**

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$parse/syntax?p0=index&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=2&p3=%26index&p4=index
y/<@http://localhost/AngularJS/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:443
cb.prototype.throwError@http://localhost/AngularJS/lib/angular/angular.min.js:168:335
cb.prototype.parse@http://localhost/AngularJS/lib/angular/angular.min.js:167:174
Yd/this.$get</<@http://localhost/AngularJS/lib/angular/angular.min.js:98:304
yd</<.link@http://localhost/AngularJS/lib/angular/angular.min.js:197:437
```

...

Comment: isn't it "track by $index" and not "&index"?

Comment: Excellent! That resolved the problem. But my images won't show up. Gotta enter another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ng-repeat you have `track by &index` change it to `track by $index`

Here's a working example: [JS BIn](http://jsbin.com/vomab/5/edit)